# Wrong coordinates of HTML elements obtained in components

Tags: angular, svg, tooltip, angular-renderer2, angular-gridster2

I've added a custom tooltip to an SVG chart within gridster item (all examples are provided on stackblitz). Tooltip (div) coordinates are obtained using `nativeElement` and set using the `Renderer2` ([trivial example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-tooltip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - tooltip div is offset by 20px). However, when I project the chart widget within gridster item, the tooltip is always added to the wrong position (see [the full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridster2-svg-tooltip) - hover over circles). It seems that for every widget, the coordinates of the div are incremented by how much that widget is far from the edges of the window (left and top).

Visually, this is how far the tooltip should be away from the circle:

[image: Normal]

But in reality (the more the element is far away from the edge of the screen, the further the tooltip is placed):

[image: Not normal]

I've tried to see if this is the problem with the `<ng-content>` i.e. the content projection within `GridsterItem`, but it doesn't seem to me like that when I make a custom component to mimic that (see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-tooltip-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)). Why are coordinates funky within gridster item? Is `renderer` setting coordinates relative to the widget, or to the `document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the tooltip position based on the client position of the circle. What you need is the position of the circle relative to its parent.

```
public mouseEnter($event, data): void {
  const circle = $event.target as HTMLElement;
  const parent = circle.parentElement;
  const circleCoords = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  const parentCoords = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  const relativeX = circleCoords.left - parentCoords.left;
  const relativeY = circleCoords.top - parentCoords.top;
  const x = `${relativeX + 20}px`;
  const y = `${relativeY + 20}px`;
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip.nativeElement, 'left', x);
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip.nativeElement, 'top', y);
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
  this.renderer.setProperty(this.tooltip.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', data);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gridster2-svg-tooltip-zubqn3?file=src/app/svg-component/svg.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: you're a life saver. I've figured that it's probably something with rendered using relative position, but I really suck with DOM. Thank you very much!